# Log-linearisation of the Euler equation

Tags: macroeconomics, rbc, log-linearization

I am struggling to log-linearize the following around the steady state:

$
U'\left(e^{z_t} F(k_t, 1) + (1 - \delta)k_t - k_{t+1}\right) - \beta E_{z_t}U'\left(e^{z_{t+1}} F(k_{t+1}, 1) + (1 - \delta)k_{t+1} - k_{t+2}\right)e^{z_{t+1}}\left(F_k(k_{t+1}, 1) + 1 - \delta\right) = 0.
$

to something of the form

$
a_1 E_{z_t} \hat{k_{t+2}} + a_2 \hat{k_{t+1}} + a_3 \hat{k_{t}} + b_1 \hat{z_t}= 0,
$

with $\hat{x}$ denoting deviations from the steady state.
I am really new to RBC theory and applied the definitions of the Taylor-Approximation, but things get very messy... I do not know if I set the Taylor-Approximation up correctly or how to simplify to get the result.
Any help is greatly appreciated!